# Enviar dato de un input

Tags: php

quisiera saber como puedo enviar el dato almacenado de un input, que no no sea el `name`. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```
<div class="col-xs-9 center-page" style="width: 83%">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <label for="ValorMTDCH"><strong>Metros Ensanche</strong><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <input style="text-align: right" type="number" value="0" name="ValorMTDCH" class="form-control" min="0" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <label for="ValorMTDPT"><strong>Metros Destape</strong><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <input style="text-align: right" type="number" value="0" name="ValorMTDPT" class="form-control" min="0" required>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <label for="ValorOtros"><strong>Otros</strong><span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <input style="text-align: right" type="number" value="0" name="ValorOtros" class="form-control" min="0" required>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Cada input tiene que registrarse, al momento de darle por metodo post recibo los datos en el controlador, pero lo envio con el identificador que es el `name`, pero quiero saber si hay otra forma...

Comment: Hasta donde se, para enviar datos de un formulario por los métodos get o post el identificador es siempre el _name_, ¿Existe alguna razón en particular para evitar utilizar el _name_ o es solo curiosidad?

Comment: No hay otra forma, el identificador siempre es el name, a menos que utilices javascript para tener mas opciones.

Comment: con javascript o jquery  renombras el valor del campo

Answer (score 2):

Realmente **sí se puede**, [a partir de HTML 5 es posible usar la propiedad `data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) la cual:

> Proporciona acceso de lectura / escritura a todos los atributos de
>   datos personalizados (`data-*`) establecidos en el elemento. Este
>   acceso está disponible tanto en HTML como dentro del DOM. Es un mapa
>   de DOMString, una entrada para cada atributo de datos personalizados.
>   Tenga en cuenta que la propiedad del conjunto de datos se puede leer,
>   pero no escribir directamente. En cambio, todas las escrituras deben
>   ser para las propiedades individuales dentro del conjunto de datos,
>   que a su vez representan los atributos de datos. Tenga en cuenta
>   también que un atributo de datos HTML y su DOM dataset.property
>   correspondiente no comparten el mismo nombre, pero siempre son
>   similares.

Observa el siguiente `input`:

```
<input id="ibxPersona" 
       data-dni="X123456" 
       data-ciudad="New York" 
       data-profesion="Informático" 
       value="John Doe" />
```

Aparte del tradicional `value`, desde HTML 5 se puede agregar información adicional en la forma: `data-identificador`, la cual se puede recuperar del modo siguiente: `elemento.dataset.identificador`.

Pero la propiedad `data-*` es mucho más poderosa. Nosotros podemos modificarla en tiempo de ejecución, borrando/modificando/agregando información.

Veamos en ejemplo:

```js
/*Referencia al input*/
const ibxPersona = document.querySelector('#ibxPersona');

/*Referencia a todo el dataset por simplicidad*/
const dataPersona = ibxPersona.dataset;

/*Valores que ya existen*/
var personaDNI = dataPersona.dni;
var personaCiudad = dataPersona.ciudad;
var personaProfesion = dataPersona.profesion;

console.log("DNI:\t" + personaDNI);
console.log("Ciudad:\t" + personaCiudad);
console.log("Prof:\t" + personaProfesion);

/*Se le puede agregar información de forma dinámica*/
dataPersona.java = true;
console.log("Ahora " + ibxPersona.value + " aprendió Java: " + dataPersona.java);

/*Se le puede quitar información*/
delete dataPersona.profesion;

/*Se puede modificar información*/
dataPersona.profesion=personaProfesion+", Escritor";

/*Cómo se muestra el data set*/
console.log(dataPersona);
```

```html
<input id="ibxPersona" data-dni="X123456" data-ciudad="New York" data-profesion="Informático" value="John Doe" />
```

Cabe decir que antes de `data*` uno podía recurrir a ciertos *trucos* para pasar varios elementos, lo cual era muy útil en algunos casos. Pero esta nueva funcionalidad hace que eso sea historia.

En la prehistoria una podía hacer cosas así:

```
<select name="selTest">
    <option value="3|5|8">Opc 1</option>
    <option value="2|4|6">Opc 2</option>
</select>
```

Aquí el `value` me estaba sirviendo para pasar *tres valores en uno*.