# ¿Cómo agregar valor predeterminado a la etiqueta <p> en HTML?

Tags: html

Uso la etiqueta `<p>` de la siguiente manera.

```html
<p contenteditable="true">Editable.</p>
```

Necesito darle un valor por default usando la propiedad `value` pero, no me muestra nada,
ejemplo:

```html
<p contenteditable="true" value="test"></p>
```

Comment: Y porque no pones el valor como en tu primer ejemplo?

Comment: En el valor necesito cargar informacion de mi `BDD`, solo necesito saber como agregar la información por default y yo puedo hacer el resto.

Comment: La etiqueta `<p>` no tiene propiedad `value`.  Si estas cargando informacion de tu `BDD`, esa informacion la puedes poner donde tu quieras, incluyendo el cuerpo de tu `<p>`.  Quizas si muestras mas codigo te podamos ayudar a lograr lo que quieres.

Comment: Necesitaba saber si era posible, con eso es suficiente (Y)

Comment: Puedes usar los atributos `data-` de HTML 5 para guardar información adicional en los elementos. Pero no se entiende lo que quieres. Si el valor `test` es para mostrarlo luego así: `<p>test</p>`  no le veo sentido a lo que quieres hacer realmente. Si fuera una información que no necesita ser mostrada en pantalla y que manejarás para otra cosa desde Javascript entonces como te dije, puedes usar los atributo `data-`  para eso. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/171516/29967)

Answer (score 0):

Como te han comentado a la etiqueta p no se le puede añadir el atributo value, de manera estática podrías hacerlo como tu primer ejemplo:

```
<p contenteditable="true">Editable.</p>
```

Pero como dices que quieres añadir valor mediante una base de datos solo necesitas añadirla entre las etiquetas, por ejemplo:

```
<p contenteditable="true"><?php echo $valor_por_defecto; ?></p>
```