# Registrar Arrays Multidimensionales - PHP

Tags: php, array

Actualmente tengo un formulario sencillo con un área de texto, solo para pruebas. Por ejemplo:

```html
 <form method="post" action="submit.php"> 
    <textarea name="textarea">
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">    
  </form>
```

Mi deseo es que el usuario copie y pegue información en el textarea asumiendo que la registraré posteriormente en una tabla con los siguientes campos:

correo | nombre | apellido | direccion | telefono

El usuario deberá respetar esta estructura independientemente de la cantidad de registros que deseen subir (Lo orientaré con un placeholder).

El tema es que si envío la información de está forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Imprimiendola en un var_dump de esta manera:

```html
<?php

$textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

$rows = preg_split("/[\n]/", $textarea);

var_dump($rows);
```

Los datos quedarían organizados de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perfectamente recorriendo el array si fuese un dato por fila yo podría registrarlo en una base de datos, pero como cada fila son diferentes campos para registrar en ese caso no veo de que manera puedo tratar los datos y poder hacer cada fila un registro, asumiendo que las filas seran "n" cantidad pero siempre con los 5 campos previamente descritos.

Cualquier ayuda para poder realizar estos registros estaría agradecido

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces uso de los atirbutos `data-` (a partir de HTML5) o de otra estrategia más simple en caso de no disponer de HTML5, como poner los datos con un separador. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/171516/29967). Me parece que hacer uso de un textarea para esto complica las cosas al usuario y al programador.

Comment: Eso puedo utilizarlo para capturar los datos desde un textarea como lo estoy enviando y luego registrarlos en la base de datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      <?php
/*Usaremos como delimitador la coma, ya que el espacio en blanco no sirve porque en tu campo dirección tienes espacios
por lo que tomaría ese campo como 2 valores ( puedes usar espacios(como delimitador) si en el campo de dirección no usas espacios en blanco) */

$textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

$rows = preg_split("/[\n]/", $textarea);
/*Hasta aqui  tu codigo es el mismo*/

/*Ya tenemos dividido el texto en registros así que los recorremos*/
foreach ($rows as $registro) {
    /*Limpiamos los espacios */
    $registro = trim($registro);

    /*Limpiamos las variable para que no se use el valor del registro anterior ( en caso que el nuevo registro no tenga ese campo) */
    $correo = $nombre = $apellido = $direccion = $telefono = '';

   /*Recuerda que tu delimitador no es un espacio en blanco es un tap, 
   así que si al copiar el código no se ejecuta bien, remplaza el espacio en 
   blanco de la función explode, por un tap, directamente en tu codigo*/
    list($correo, $nombre , $apellido , $direccion , $telefono) = explode(' ',$registro);

    echo "
    Correo: $correo <br>
    Nombre: $nombre <br>
    Apellido: $apellido <br>
    Direccion: $direccion <br>
    Telefono: $telefono <br><br>"; 

}

?>
```

Te dejo el codigo original aquí ( por si tienes problemas con el delimitador):
[Ejemplo en google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SMMpF66_v12azzXD1fWk_ODvS9_-GagZ)

Como se puede observar, el texto delimitador( de color gris) generado por excel, no es un espacio en blanco es un tap( puedes ver que es más grande que un espacio en blanco normal 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu codigo en gran parte hace lo que necesito a excepción del limitador ya que necesito que sea por espacios, pero no entiendo por que dices que mis correos tienen espacios, ningun correo debe tener espacios, es más debo validarlos y quitarle espacios en caso de que lo tengas y solo debe contener como elemento delimitador.

Comment: Lo más importante que destacar es que lo que realmente deseo es copiar texto desde excel y pegarlo en el textarea, aunque copiar el texto de excel y pegarlo en el textarea me separa los campos en el text area solo me detecta los espacios de las direcciones que tienen espacios, los espacios por defecto que asigna html al pegar el excel no los detecta como espacios.

Comment: En pocas palabras lo que necesitaria modificarle a tu codigo es hacerle explode a las celdas de excel y estoy hecho

Comment: Es que el espacio entre las palabras de excel no es un espacio en blanco, es un tap, voy a cambiar el delimitador por un tab. espero y te funcione

Comment: Al copiar el código, el tap, se reemplaza por un espacio en blanco y no funciona bien asi que aqui te dejo el codigo original para que te corra bien

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SMMpF66_v12azzXD1fWk_ODvS9_-GagZ?usp=sharing